# Delete files before uploading via Fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

(using fineuploader with Traditional endpoints)

Application flow:

- User will upload several files
- Server will perform some backend operations on theses files
- Files will then be deleted

Because of these "backend operations" it would be cleaner to delete all the files in the upload directory before any files are uploaded.  Fineuploader has a lot of callbacks.  My thinking was add a callback for [validateBatch](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validateBatch).  Then I could kick off my delete operation, but how do I then indicate to fine uploader to continue.

Comment: This sounds like something your server should handle, and your client should not be aware of at all. Instead of pulling Fine Uploader into this, just create some scheduled task server-side that deletes these files.

Comment: Yes, I do plan to have the server delete the files once it's done processing the files, but what if this fails for some reason.

Comment: ...make sure it doesn't? Involving your browser side code is definitely the wrong approach.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your advice!  Is there a simple way that each set of uploaded files could get its own unique (preferably random) directory?  I'm using your: [php-traditional-server](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server).  I don't see how to do this off hand sense the endpoint gets called per file instead of per batch of files.

Comment: Yes there is a way. This is a generic php question, unrelated to fine uploader though

Comment: I know how to do this in PHP as I've done it several times.  I don't know how to integrate it with fineuploader sense the endpoint gets called per file instead of per batch of files.

Comment: first, what is a "batch" of files? how do you define that?

Comment: A batch is either a group of files that the user selects from a file upload dialog or a single file in the case of a failure+retry.